# Missing "operation links" from all content list page

Tags: nodes, users

I am currently missing the links that appear next to a piece of content on admin/content, the ones that say "edit / delete" etc.
I have all permissions enabled for the user I am logged in as, and I can still edit a piece of content if I go to view it first, just not on the list page.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: This occurs when you enable a separate theme for the administration section and enable "Use administration theme for content editing" .

Comment: I don't understand, please explain.

Comment: The site is using Seven the default admin theme.

Comment: are they still gone when logged in a user 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to re-install the latest version of Drupal.